# Show that $(1,0,1), (-2,1,4), (0,3,1)$ forms the basis for $\in \mathbb {R^3}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

I want to show that $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ forms the basis for $\in \mathbb {R^3}$. First I tried to show that the vectors are linearly independent

$$α_1\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + α_2\begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} + α_3\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

But I tried to continue from this on wards but I get that $α_3=18α_3$, which doesn't make sense so I'm a bit lost.

$$α_1\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + α_2\begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} + α_3\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Assuming your working is correct, what value of $\alpha_3$ solves $\alpha_3=18\alpha_3$?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your work, but you may well have gotten a contradiction (not really), because because you *can't* find *non-zero* $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ to satisfy that equation unless they are linearly *dependent* (not independent).

Comment: $\alpha_3= 18\alpha_3$ is the same as (subtract $\alpha_3$ from both sides) $17\alpha_3= 0$. Dividing both sides by 17, $\alpha= 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$α_1\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + α_2\begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} + α_3\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
You got a system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}\alpha_1-2\alpha_2&=0\\\alpha_2+3\alpha_3&=0\\\alpha_1+4\alpha_2+\alpha_3&=0 \end{cases}
\implies\begin{cases}\alpha_1=2\alpha_2\\\alpha_3=-\frac13\alpha_2\\ 2\alpha_2+4\alpha_2-\frac13\alpha_2=0 \implies\alpha_2=\alpha_1=\alpha_3=0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3):

Another equivalent way to @Lorenzo is to show that the determinant of 
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & 4 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
is not zero. Doing this will give you:
\begin{equation}
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & 4 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
=
1(1 - 12) + 1(-6 + 0) = -11 - 6 = -17 \neq 0
\end{equation}